# Trying to display pop-up in angular before making REST call through JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing an issue.

I've a button in angular like this :

```
<button ng-click = "makeRestCall()">
</button>
```

This is what the Javascript code looks like :

```
$scope.makeRestCall = function() {
    console.log('Logic to make rest call...');        
};
```

Now the issue is when I click the button, instead of it directly making the REST call through JS, I want it to display a pop-up for confirmation. If yes, then the function is called, else no.

Can someone help?

Comment: sounds like you need a **modal** that will confirm it with an asynchronous callback, which, once resolved, will make an AJAX call (with `$http` service). Making such modal can be too broad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create use simple `confirm` box of browser (to make it more intuitive in future you can use [`alertify`](https://alertifyjs.com/guide.html) plugin that will make popup UI consistent across browser )

```
$scope.makeRestCall = function() {
  var accepted = confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed.')
  if(accepted)
  console.log('Logic to make rest call...');
};
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RxMnbOXRFiS1aA1sUN0s?p=preview)

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RxMnbOXRFiS1aA1sUN0s?p=preview) with Alertify

---

Further extending this, it would be bad solution if you keep on repeating same amount of code on every place. This way would violet the DRY principle of ACID. Better we write logic once and use it everywhere. In angular you can create a directive for the same.

**Directive**

```
.directive('confirmAndSubmit', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function() {
          alertify.confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed.', function() {
            scope.$eval(attrs.submitCallback);
          })
        })
      }
    };
});
```

**Usage**

```
<button confirm-and-submit submit-callback="makeRestCall()">
    Make Rest Call
</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.makeRestCall = function() {
    console.log('Logic to make rest call...')
};
```

[**Running demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6NfoeLW1Hvai6hTuWXMI?p=preview) with Directive